# When a new line is started, VSCode only inserts indentations when the Enter is pressed just after the operators or parentheses

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, editor, indentation

I am using the vscode for R programming now. Recently, I noticed that the auto-indentation only works when you press *Enter* just after an operator such as `+-*/` or the parentheses and brackets.

For example, suppose we have the `print(a)` in a line. Pressing Enter with the cursor before `a` yields

```
print(
  a)
```

Meanwhile, moving the cursor after `a`, typing a comma and hitting Enter results in

```
print(a,
)
```

The scenario indicated by the second case occurs when I want to type the function arguments on a new line, where an indentation is typically expected. Where can I adjust this on-Enter indentation rule?

The setting seems to be language-specific. I test similar things in Python with VSCode and everything looks fine.

```
# np.matmul(X1,<press Enter here>)
# then it appears like:
np.matmul(X1,
          )
```